# Cannot link pdcurses static debug build with VS2013

Tags: c++, pdcurses

I downloaded and compiled pdcurses. As instructed from their documentation I used:

```
nmake -f vcwin32.mak DEBUG=Y pdcurses.lib
```

I also build pdcurses without the DEBUG tag so I can be on release mode.

Now, I have a project where I want to statically link pdcurses.
I use MT and MTd as runtime libraries and I link the .lib files from DEBUG build when I'm on debug and the other .lib files when I'm on release.

When I build my project on release mode everything works fine but when I try to build on debug here is the error:

```
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invoke_watson(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invoke_watson@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __call_reportfault already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __initp_misc_invarg already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: ___pInvalidArgHandler already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to both the debug and release static runtimes, don't do that. If you don't know which of your libraries is causing the issue then see [this guide](http://brianfosterallen.com/devblog/blog/2013/07/18/tracking-down-conflicting-runtime-libs-in-msvc/) for steps on detecting that.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the problem but I don't do that. Not in purpose at least. I build on debug runtime the pdcurses and then I link with MTd. What's the problem?